# Can there be a hierarchy with sitecore tags

Tags: tags, sitecore

Is it possible to have a hierarchy for sitecore tags ?

Example for say transportation tags.

Bike

_ Women's bike

_ Men's bike

_ Children's bike

Car

_ Ford

_ Volkswagen

_ Peugot

When I search for Ford I want to get all the items tagged Ford. When I search for Car I want to get all items tagged Car, Ford, Volkswagen and/or Peugot.

When an item is tagged Ford it would also not need to be tagged as a car separately.

( Edited to give a better explaination )

Comment: Hey Timon.. try to give us more details in what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @RobertoBr, Say i have a bunch of transportation items ( bikes, cars, trains ). Each of these options have subcategories i would also like to be able to tag on. ( bikes would have womenbike, menbike, childrenbike. Cars would have ford, mercedes, peugot, ... ) I want to be able to tag on ALL tags mentioned above and when i facet on say bike i would also get the womenbikes, menbikes and childrenbikes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The out-of-the-box Sitecore Search infrastructure doesn't support this directly - as it doesn't know how about the tree structure of your tags. It is possible to extend the Lucene integration to enable it, however.

First, some assumptions:

1) The tags
I'm assuming you have a tree of tag content somewhere in your Sitecore data. Each tag is created based on a "Tag" template so it can be recognised as a tag. For example, your content tree might look like:

```
Tags               --> Uses "Folder" template
   Car             --> Uses "Tag" template
     Ford          --> Uses "Tag" template
     Volkswagen    --> Uses "Tag" template
   Bike            --> Uses "Tag" template
     Mens Bike     --> Uses "Tag" template
     Womens Bike   --> Uses "Tag" template
```

2) Applying tags
Your content items (ie the ones that are being tagged) have a TreeList (or TreeListEx) field whose data source is your "Tags" folder from point #1. This allows the editors to pick a selection of tags as they see fit. I will assume this field is called "AppliedTags"

With that in place:

You need to implement some code that means when the Search index is built, it attaches the tag the editor used, as well as any parent tags of that tag item. So if the editor attaches "Ford" then "Car" is put into the Lucene Index too.

You don't specify the version of Sitecore you're using - but the general idea is the same for recent versions. There are some technical differences in older versions, however.

In Sitecore 7.x (and probably 8 too) you need to create a "Computed Index Field". This is basically some custom code that Sitecore runs before passing your Item data to Lucene for indexing. You can use this custom code to compute a new field for Lucene containing the expanded set of tags. An overview of computed fields in SC7 is given in these links: (there is more stuff out there - google for more detail)

http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/03/Sitecore-7-Computed-Index-Fields.aspx

http://reasoncodeexample.com/2014/04/01/computed-index-fields-sitecore-7-content-search/

When called, your custom code will receive the Sitecore Item that is currently being indexed. In pseudocode, your computed field code can then:

```
If the item being processed has an "AppliedTags" field
  Create a list to store results
  For each Tag item specified in the current Item's "AppliedTags" field
      Run a Sitecore Query API to find any ancestors of that Tag which are themselves Tags
      Add the IDs of each of these returned items to the results list
  Return the results list
```

The test for whether the item has the "AppliedTags" field is required because your code will be run against every item that is being processed for this search index. Hence the code would break when it encountered an item whose template did not have this field. I'm assuming you have items that can't have tags in your content tree.

Now the Lucene Index can contain data for all the applied tags and their parents - so the search result you want is now possible. It will also work with deeper trees of tags - though take care as the bigger your tag tree, the more processing is required at indexing time.

You need to modify the Sitecore configuration for Lucene to add your computed field to the list of fields for your search index. You'll find instructions for this in the standard Sitecore search docs - but I'll assume the new index field is called "ExpandedTags".

With that done (and your index rebuilt to get all the new data) you can then write a Sitecore Search query that says `Search the "ExpandedTags" index entry for "Car"` and it will return things that were originally tagged with "Ford" and "Volkswagen" as well.

In Sitecore 6.5/6.6 I don't think you can do this out-of-the-box without a lot of effort, but there was an open-source extension to the search infrastructure:

https://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib

The "crawler" part of this project enables the use of classes based on `scSearchContrib.Crawler.DynamicFields.BaseDynamicField` to do much the same thing as above. If you use this extension to generate your search index then you can apply a similar customisation approach as above. There's a simple example of using Dynamic Fields here:

http://www.letsdositecore.com/advanced-database-crawler-and-dynamic-fields/

However, getting this search framework running will involve some extra work to ensure Sitecore uses the SearchContrib framework to build your indexes. Example configuration patches are provided in the github data linked above.

Comment: Thanks JermDavid, this is just what I was looking for. ( I will use sitecore 8 so this should work like a charm )

Answer (score 1):

Tagging is a way of structuring content in a non-hierarchical way. So applying them isn't done hierarchically. But you can create multiple tag repositories to store your tags in. You can see an example in this very informative blog post (under "Create your own tags"): https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/tagging-is-fun-in-sitecore/

Answer (score 0):

Use **Sitecore Item Buckets**  functionality in sitecore,
search are already there in sitecore7.0 and upper version,by using sitecore search Tag1 gives you all realted tag1 content